# Remove extra padding from navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I want to remove extra padding from navbar but not able to do even after making bottom padding 0.It is below navbar options. Also i have searched on web but not able to get solution.
Below is the html code

```
<div class="navbar  navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img style="max-width: 100px; margin-top: -7px;"
                        src="images/Logo.png">
                </a>
                <div class="complete">

                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" style="background-color: gray;" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="background-color: lightgray;">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li role="presentation"><a runat="server" href="/Default">Home</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a runat="server" href="/Report"> Report</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a runat="server" href="/server">server</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a runat="server" href="/Engine">Management</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a runat="server" href="/Class">Management</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a runat="server" href="/User">User</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and CSS code

```
 `
  /* --- Style --- */
  body {
  padding-top: 150px;
  }

  .navbar{
     background-color:darkseagreen;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     }

  .navbar-header{
     background-color:darkseagreen;
     padding-top: 4px;
     padding-bottom:4px;
  } 
  .nav {
     background-color:forestgreen;
     margin-top:0px;
     margin-bottom:0px;
  }
  `
```

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: is there a reason you have  
body {
  padding-top: 150px;
  }
? because if I understand your question correctly, this cause the top padding on nav bar

Comment: which padding you want to remove?

Comment: @BilalAhmed below navbar

Comment: ok.. i am upload some code try this and update me...

Comment: @k185 yes because if i remove it then the body content will be overlapping with navbar

Comment: if you want some more changes then reply me

Comment: @BilalAhmed what did you change? i want navbar below logo and other things. and both fixed at top

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this once and don't add style to this code and check it once.**

```
<div class="navbar  navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img style="max-width: 100px; margin-top: -7px;"
                src="images/Logo.png">
        </a>
        <div class="complete">

        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" style="background-color: gray;" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="background-color: forestgreen;">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li role="presentation"><a runat="server" href="/Default">Home</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a runat="server" href="/Report"> Report</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a runat="server" href="/server">server</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a runat="server" href="/Engine">Management</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a runat="server" href="/Class">Management</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a runat="server" href="/User">User</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
         <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no this does not work. i want navbar below logo and both fix

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* --- Style --- */
  body {
  padding-top: 150px;
  }

  .navbar{
     background-color:darkseagreen;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     }

  .navbar-header{
     background-color:darkseagreen;
     padding-top: 4px;
     padding-bottom:4px;
  } 
  .nav {
     background-color:forestgreen;
     margin-top:0px;
     margin-bottom:0px;
  }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar  navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img style="max-width: 100px; margin-top: -7px;"
                        src="images/Logo.png">
                </a>
                <div class="complete">

                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" style="background-color: gray; margin-bottom: 0px;" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="background-color: lightgray;">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li role="presentation"><a runat="server" href="/Default">Home</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a runat="server" href="/Report"> Report</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a runat="server" href="/server">server</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a runat="server" href="/Engine">Management</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a runat="server" href="/Class">Management</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a runat="server" href="/User">User</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about it is `.navbar{ padding-bottom: 0px }`

Answer (score -1):

Try this css code

```css
body {
  margin:0px;
  padding-top: 150px;
  }
```